# How to convert map into my desirable list?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a map form firestore in a format like:

`{potato: {unit: kg, quantity: 2, pname: potato, price: 50.0, document: potato, imagestring: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/xxx, pid: potato, category: veg}, tomato: {unit: kg, quantity: 1, pname: tomato, price: 40.0, document: tomato, imagestring: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/yyy, pid: tomato, category: veg}}`

i want to convert it to a list of product where each section like potato{} , tomato{}
is added as a new element in list like a normal for each function where :

```
unit:element.data['unit']
```

etc.

I already have class

```
class Product{
String unit;
...
...
}
```

and i want to add it to list

```
List<Product> list=[];
```

Comment: If this still an issue for you? Did the below answers help you resolve the issue or do you still need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to [model your JSON into a class structure](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) and give it methods to interchange from JSON to class, and from class to JSON.
Add your other attributes, this is shortened.

```
    class Product{
        String unit;
        String quantity;.

        Product(this.unit, this.quantity);//default constructor

        //Make a new class instance from json data from db
        Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,) :
        unit= json['unit'],
        quantity = json['quantity'];

        //make a json payload from this class instance
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
        { 'unit' : unit, 'quantity' : quantity }
    }
```

[Add it to the list](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html):

```
List<Product> list= [ Product.fromJson(element) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
class FireStoreData{
Potato potato;
Tomato tomato;
FireStoreData({this.potato, this.tomato});
factory FireStoreData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => FireStoreData(
.........
);
}
class Potato{
String unit;
int quantity;
....
Potato({this.unit, this.quantity....});
factory Potato.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => Potato(
unit: jsonData['uni'],
quantity: jsonData['quantity],
........
);
}
Create a same class for Tomato
```

You need a bit of Rest API knowledge to implement this.

Comment: you can use this site [link](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=dart) to build the class quickly. u need to add Constructor and factory convertion to your class i dunno if you have any.